# Probablity question answer check

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I'm not sure if my answer is correct, so I would be glad if you could help me.

> There are eight cities, and a flight connection between any 2. Due to bad weather conditions flights on 9 of these connections have been canceled. If we choose 4 connections randomly, what's the probability of the case, where EXACTLY 2 connections are "open".

My solution:

We have $8*7/2=28$ connections,
$\binom{20}{9}$ ways to select the 9 connections and $\binom{20}{4}$ to select four.

The probability of having choosen exactly 2 open connections is: $\binom{20}{4}*\frac{9}{28}*\frac{8}{27}*\frac{21}{26}*\frac{20}{25}$

So the solution:
$$\frac{\binom{20}{4}*\frac{9}{28}*\frac{8}{27}*\frac{21}{26}*\frac{20}{25}}{\binom{20}{9}}$$

But somehow this doesn't feel right. Is there anything I missed?
Thanks!

Comment: It sounds legit to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have messed up something in your reasoning. I am not certain, but feels like you haven't taken correctly into account the order (or lack thereof) in which you choose.

There is an easier (and in my opinion more transparent) way. There are $28$ connections, and you choose four of them. So we get part of the solution:
$$
P(\text{exactly 2 broken}) = \frac{}{\binom{28}{4}}
$$
Now, for the numerator, there are $9$ broken and $28-9 = 19$ unbroken lines. Two broken lines can be chosen in $\binom{9}{2}$ ways, and two that are still up can be chosen in $\binom{19}{2}$ ways. So the final answer is
$$
P(\text{exactly 2 broken}) = \frac{\binom{9}{2}\binom{19}{2}}{\binom{28}{4}}
$$
This is called hypergeometric probability.

Comment: Yes, that part was the one that seemed messy to me too. Thanks for the clear explanation!